# Hyperlinks are being overwritten in emails

Tags: zend-framework, email, sendgrid

I am sending out emails from my website using Zend_Mail and Send Grid. I have hyperlinks in the email that are being overwritten with what appears to be garbage by the time it gets to the user's inbox.

For example,

href="http://www.foo.com" is becoming href="http://email.foo.com/wf/click?upn=DSDRHSSBH2938TS".

I do not have this problem when I remove the 'http://' from the href. This is not a solution for me however, because links without 'http://' do not work in some email clients.

I checked the Zend Mail content and the links appear to be fine, so I am wondering if this is a problem with Send Grid or the email client. I have looked all over the web and have found very little information on this. I have seen some people with similar issues, but no one has been able to provide a real solution.

Has anyone seen anything like this? I'll be happy to provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Send Grid is re-writing the URLs for click tracking. Try disabling this feature in your Send Grid account. https://sendgrid.com/docs/Apps/click_tracking.html